# Solving a trig equation $1+ \sin (x)=2 \cos(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

How would I solve the following equation?
$$
1+ \sin (x)=2 \cos(x)
$$
I am having difficult with it.

Answer (score 6):

We have $1 + \sin(x) = 2 \cos(x)$. Recall that $1 - \sin^2(x) = \cos^2(x)$. Hence, we get that $$(1 + \sin(x))(1- \sin(x)) = \cos^2(x)$$ i.e. 
$$2 \cos(x) (1 - \sin(x)) = \cos^2(x)$$
If $\cos(x) \neq 0$, then we get that $$1 - \sin(x) = \dfrac{\cos(x)}2$$
Hence, have
\begin{align}
1 + \sin(x) & = 2\cos(x)\\
1 - \sin(x) & = \dfrac{\cos(x)}2
\end{align}
This gives us that $2 = \dfrac52 \cos(x) \implies \cos(x) = \dfrac45$. This gives us $\sin(x) = \dfrac35$. Hence, we get one possible solution as $$x = 2n \pi + \theta$$ where $\sin(\theta) = \dfrac35$ with $0 < \theta < \dfrac{\pi}2$.

If $\cos(x) = 0$, then we need $\sin(x) = -1$. Hence, $x = 2n\pi + \dfrac{3 \pi}2$.

Comment: ,according to my method, $x=\arccos \frac45=\arcsin\frac45$ is another solution.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Try plugging your answer in... $1 + \frac{4}{5} \neq 2 \cdot \frac{4}{5}$, so it looks like something went wrong.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks. Yes. the other solution is $x = \arcsin(3/5) = \arccos(4/5)$.

Comment: @andybenji, sorry there was terrible typo--it should be $\arcsin\frac35=\arccos\frac45$ as Marvis has noted.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Square both sides, and express $\cos^2 x$ in terms of $\sin^2 x$.

You will get a quadratic equation in $\sin^2 x$. After finding the solutions of this equation, make sure to substitute into the *original* equation to check whether they are indeed roots of the original equation. The squaring process could produce "spurious" roots. (It happens not to, but checking is cheap.)

Comment: I have a quick question I squared both sides and got. 1+2sin(x)+sin^2(x)=4cos^2(x) so I made 4cos^2(x) into 4-sin^2(x) Is this correct.

Comment: It would be $4-4\sin^2 x$. The equation then becomes $5\sin^2 x+2\sin x-3=0$. You can then use the Quadratic Formula or factor as $(5\sin x-3)(\sin x+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

This may be the hard way, but if you let $q=\tan(x/2)$, then $\sin x=2q/(1+q^2)$, and $\cos x=(1-q^2)/(1+q^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me take a stab at this.  I had to double check a few identities.  First, we use the identities $\cos(\frac\pi 2-x)=\sin x$ and $\sin(\frac\pi 2-x)=\cos x$.

$$1+\cos(\frac\pi 2-x)=2\sin(\frac\pi 2-x)$$
$$\frac{1+\cos(\frac\pi 2-x)}{\sin(\frac\pi 2-x)}=2$$

Next, we use the half-angle identity $\tan\frac\theta 2=\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}$.

$$\cot(\frac\pi 4-\frac x2)=2$$
$$\tan(\frac\pi 4-\frac x2)=\frac12$$

From here, take the inverse tangent and the rest is algebra.

Comment: $\cos\left(\frac\pi4-\frac x2\right)$ can also be $0$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I see how I might have lost some roots by not making sure $\cos x$, or $\sin(\frac\pi 2-x)$ if you prefer, was 0 before dividing by it.  Did I lose roots in any other step somehow?

Answer (score 1):

We can try to avoid squaring to avoid tests for [extraneous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) root.
$$2\cos x-\sin x=1$$

Putting $r\cos\theta=2,r\sin\theta=1$ where $r>0 $

Squaring and adding we get $r^2=2^2+1^2\implies r=\sqrt5$

On division, $\tan \theta=\frac12$ where $0<\theta<\frac\pi2$ as $\sin\theta,\cos\theta>0$

we get $$\cos\theta\cos x-\sin\theta\sin x=\sin\theta$$(cancelling $r$ in either sides )

or, $\cos(x+\theta)=\cos(\frac\pi2-\theta)$

So, $$x+\theta=2n\pi\pm\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right)$$
 where $n$ is any integer.

Taking $'-'$ sign, $$x+\theta=2n\pi-\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right)\implies x=2n\pi-\frac\pi2$$

Taking $'+'$ sign, $$x+\theta=2n\pi+\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right)\implies x=2n\pi+\frac\pi2-2\theta=2n\pi+\frac\pi2-2\arctan \frac12$$

Now, we know $\cos2y=\frac{1-\tan^2y}{1+\tan^2y},\sin2y=\frac{2\tan y}{1+\tan^2y},\tan2y=\frac{2\tan y}{1-\tan^2y}$

If $\arctan \frac12=y,\tan y=\frac 12$

$$\cos2y=\frac35,\sin2y=\frac45,\tan2y=\frac43$$

So, $$2y=2\arctan \frac12=\arccos\frac35=\arcsin\frac45=\arctan \frac43$$

So, $$x=2n\pi+\frac\pi2-\arccos\frac35=2n\pi+\arcsin\frac35$$ as $\arcsin z+\arccos z=\frac12$ for  $-1\le z\le1$

Similarly, $$x=2n\pi+\arccos\frac45=2n\pi+\operatorname{arccot}\frac43$$

Comment: It is not clear we should *avoid* squaring, since checking is cheap. A good reason to avoid squaring is if degree is increased beyond the comfortable. But degree $2$ is comfortable.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, squaring is easing the calculation a lot  for $A\cos x+B\sin x=C$  w/o introducing much intricacies. There is no extraneous root as such,right?. We just need to identify the quadrant of $x$ by getting the sign of $\cos x$  from the given equation, if we have the quadratic equation in $\sin x$ or vice versa. Is $\arccot$ not a valid latex?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Apparently not. Try "\mathrm{arccot}"